# Getting maxJsonLength property error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Getting error:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   System.Web.Extensions.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Error during serialization or deserialization
>   using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds
>   the value set on the maxJsonLength property.

In my appsetting file I have added :

```
<add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="2147483647" />
```

and in my webconfig file i have added :

```
 <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483647"/>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
    </system.web.extensions>
```

Still I am getting error.

The error occuring in "return" and this is my C# code:

```
  public String GetBulkContacts(string KeyName, string GroupName)
        {
            var result = _bulkMailService.GetBulkMailContacts(KeyName, GroupName);
            return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(result);
        }
```

Comment: Where is this error occurring? Show us the code that deserializes and what JSON is being deserialized?

Comment: I have updated my code plz check once @Milney

Comment: set `<jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000"/>` and try once

Comment: SerializeObject is not exit in the jsonconvert @Milney

Comment: @kumarswamy You may need to reference Newtonsoft.Json to use JsonConvert, however my answer covers how to fix javascriptserializer if you prefer using that

Comment: @kumarswamy, install Newtonsoft.json from nuget package manager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change to this;

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
serializer.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;
return serializer.Serialize(result);
```

As far as I am aware the web.config setting is only for the MVC internal serializer and **not** for ones you instance yourself...

You could also use;

```
return new JsonResult()
    {
        Data = result,
        MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue
    };
```

instead. Also I think you should use

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
```

instead of a direct JavaScriptSerializer these days.

Comment: JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result); i am trying to use byt unbale to use this @Milney

Comment: @kumarswamy unable in what way?... Try reading the documentation: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm